# How to pass login screen activity when using onBackPressed

Tags: android

My app has three main activity.

1. Splash Activity
2. Login Activity
3. Menu Activity

When I start app, splash screen work with four second, then it goes login activity. If user login successfully then app goes menu activity. In my menu, there is logout button. If user clicks it, then app goes login activity.It works fine. But if users don't want to logout and click back button on devices, I want to exit from app directly. If I couldn't find solution for this problem, users have to go login screen, then splash screen and finally exit when they want to exit from app with using back button. Which solution should I use?

Comment: Keyboardsurfer has the right answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After the login has been successful you can call `finish()` on your Login Activity just after you started your Menu Activity. This effectively removes the Login Activity from the back stack.

Edit: As mentioned in the comment below, this also applies to your Splash Activity.

Comment: Also the same for Splash Activity.

Comment: It's great solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by @Keyboardsurfer will work extremely good for you, but if you want to handle Back button event then use below code to get notified about back button event.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");  
        // your code to handle back button event.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the login is successful you should call your Menu Activity as follows:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

I think you are checking in your Splash Activity if the user is logged via SharedPreferences, you should close your Splash Activity in the same way that you specify when you call any of the two activities.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the Activity's (Splash only) onPause method:

Here is how;

```
 @Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
    this.finish();

}
```

and in login activity call the finish method after the login stuff is done. Answer Edited (See the discussion below)

Comment: If the user navigates away from the Activity i.g. turns off the screen or rotates the device, onPause will be called thus finishing the Activity. This will result in unexpected behaviour and confuse the app's users.

Comment: I think in second activity (login), it may cause issue (as per the conditions u mentioned).

Comment: I think Keyboardsurfer and Deadlock say right, it may cause unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would cause unexpected behaviour in other `Activities`, only the `Splash Activity` cause its its `onPause()` that was override not the others, and since splash is only called once i don't think it matters.